# xsl - best way to set the font / font-size for the contents

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm working on a xsl / xsl-fo version 1.0 application and I found that the font and font-size are every where. Is there any way to unite the font / font-size from for example root?

I did this in xsl-fo:
`<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"  font-family="{$g_fontFamily}" font-size="11pt">`

Could anyone suggest how to do the same thing from xsl `<xsl:template match="/">`
Now it puts the font / font-size in `<css class>`, or directly wrap the `<font size="0.5em">Real Contents which need the font and font-size customized</font>`

Comment: You'll need to set the font at a node that will appear in the output. Presumably, your `template match="/"` contains an `fo:root` as part of its output, so that's the highest level where you can set the font. Alternatively, use named templates to set the text attributes, so you can just call a template from everywhere that needs text with those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute sets. This works like CSS styles.

```
      <xsl:attribute-set name="smallerFont">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">14pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="largerFont">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">40pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
...
                            <fo:table-row border-after-style="solid"
                                border-after-width="0.01mm">
                                <fo:table-cell column-number="1"
                                    number-columns-spanned="2">
                                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="largerFont"> 
                                        <xsl:value-of select="txtEarmarkedMaterial" />
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
...
```